# Получить текстовое значение каждого элемента определенного класса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть блок такого типа:

```
<span class="text">1</span>
<span class="text">2</span>
<span class="text">3</span>
<span class="text">4</span>
<span class="text">5</span>
<span class="text">6</span>
```

как можно с помощью js или jquery получить значение всех элементов и превратить их в массив? То есть ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

js:

```js
const allNums = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
let nums = [];
allNums.forEach(e => {
    nums.push(e.textContent)
})
console.log(nums)
```

Можно использовать стрелочную функцию в полной мере

```js
const allNums = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
let nums = [];
allNums.forEach(e => nums.push(e.textContent))
console.log(nums)
```

Comment: это будет работать с document.write ?

Comment: @Vlad да. но он устарел и лучше его не использовать. есть textContent

Comment: Да, опишите как именно вы его хотите увидеть в html и я допишу ф-цию

Comment: Спасибо, я понял

Comment: `console.log( [...document.querySelectorAll('.text')].map( e => e.textContent ) )` ?)

Comment: @Vlad отметьте ответ как верный если он вас всем устроил

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно вместо .text установить .user-list tr td:first-child ?

Comment: @Vlad Webfox#9868 звоните в дискорд, я не вижу код и могу что-то не то сказать

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/76nj0pos/1/

Comment: @Vlad document.querySelector('.user-list td'); скорее всего так

Comment: как можно сделать чтобы оно было в формате ["1"] ? просто сейчас оно в формате просто 1 и не хочет работать

Comment: @Vlad document.querySelectorAll('.user-list td'); скорее всего

Comment: последний вопрос, как можно добавить в начало каждого значения "+"?

Comment: @Vlad nums.push(e.textContent) в этом месте изменить на nums.push("+" + e.textContent)

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает

Comment: @Vlad если вам это помогло то есть стрелочка вверх возле моих комментариев, это как - + репутация за более обширный ответ, если я все так сделал поставьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = $('.text').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text">1</span>
<span class="text">2</span>
<span class="text">3</span>
<span class="text">4</span>
<span class="text">5</span>
<span class="text">6</span>
```

Comment: это будет работать с document.write ?

Comment: При чем здесь `document.write`? Это будет работать с чем угодно.

Comment: Можно исчо `.map( (_, e) => $(e).text() )`

Comment: `JSON.stringify(a)`  не массив `Array.isArray(JSON.stringify(a))` выдаст `false` так как это объект

Comment: @Greg-- `console.log( Array.isArray(a) ); // true`

Comment: Я понимаю, я не понял зачем добавлять эту строку

Comment: @Greg-- Мне больше нравится вывод массива в одну строку.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.text') // получаем NodeList 
 let arr = [] // объявляем массив 
 elements.forEach(e=>{ // для каждого элемена
  arr.push(e.textContent || e.innerText) // получаем содержимое и добавляем в массив 
 })
 console.log(arr)
```

```html
<span class="text">1</span>
<span class="text">2</span>
<span class="text">3</span>
<span class="text">4</span>
<span class="text">5</span>
<span class="text">6</span>
```